# Problema com JTable

Tags: java

Estou com um problema em um JTable. Fiz um método na DAO que calcula um total de produtos consumidos, este método é chamado na Tela no botão cadastrar, toda vez que cadastro um consumo preciso que vá calculando a quantidade de acordo com o valor do produto e mostra um valor total. Na verdade ele está calculando porém apenas no primeiro cadastro, caso eu cadastre outros consumos, o que me mostra na tela é apenas o primeiro consumo, caso eu delete outros e deixe apenas o consumo da primeira linha da tabela é somente este que será visualizado. Abaixo o código do método.

**Método da DAO:**

```
public Object mostra(String buscar) {

    Consumo consumoVO = new Consumo();
    ConsumoDAO consumoDAO = new ConsumoDAO();
    ModeloTabelaConsumo modelo = new ModeloTabelaConsumo();
    totalConsumo = 0.0;

    String sql = ("SELECT c.codConsumo, c.codHospedagem, c.codProduto, p.nomeProduto, " +
                  " c.quantidade, c.valorConsumo, c.status " +
                  " from consumo c " +
                  " INNER JOIN produto  p ON c.codProduto = p.codProduto " +
                   "INNER JOIN hospedagem AS H ON H.codHospedagem = C.codHospedagem " 
                 + " WHERE c.codHospedagem = " + buscar + " order by c.codConsumo ");

    getBanco().abrir();
    try {
        Statement stm = getBanco().getConexao().createStatement();
        //Faz a leitura no banco
        ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery(sql);

        if (rs.next() == true) { //Achou
            consumoVO = new Consumo();
            consumoVO.setCodConsumo(rs.getInt("codConsumo"));
            consumoVO.setCodHospedagem(rs.getInt("codHospedagem"));
            consumoVO.setCodProduto(rs.getInt("codProduto"));
            consumoVO.setCodProduto(rs.getInt("nomeProduto"));                               
            consumoVO.setQuantidade(rs.getInt("quantidade"));
            consumoVO.setValorConsumo(rs.getDouble("valorConsumo"));
            consumoVO.setStatus(rs.getString("status"));

            totalConsumo = totalConsumo + (rs.getInt("quantidade") * rs.getDouble("valorConsumo"));

           } 

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return consumoVO;
}
```

**Método da Tela Consumo:**

```
void mostrar(String buscar){
   consumoDAO.mostra(buscar);     
    lblTotalConsumo.setText("Valor R$. " + consumoDAO.totalConsumo);

}
```

Comment: Adicione um [mcve]. Não pra pra analisar apenas com o código informado.

Comment: Obg Diego F!! Esse método está funcionando, mas acredito que não esteja vendo as linhas add na tabela e não sei como fazer, cadastra novos consumos, mas o cálculo aparece apenas no primeiro cadastro que faço, ou na primeira linha, caso vou deletando outros consumos.

Answer (score 1):

O que ocorreu aí é um erro de lógica. O problema está no seu `if` para verificar se encontrou o item, mas na verdade no lugar do `if` deveria ser um `while`. Por isso ele só retorna o valor do primeiro item. Com o `while` o seu `totalConsumo` irá retornar corretamente.

Como está: `if (rs.next()) { //Achou`

Como deve ficar: `while (rs.next()) { //Achou`

E como nosso colega Diego F. informou, não é preciso comparar com true, pois o método `next()` já retorna um `boolean`.

Comment: Nâo precisa comparar com true,, resulset.next() vai sempre retornar um booleano, true quando houver mais uma "linha", false quando o cursor acabar. Logo, é redundante esse `rs.next() == true`

Comment: realmente, porque o rs.next() já retorna um boolean.
Copiei e colei do código dele e nem reparei rs. Obrigado.

Comment: Muito Obrigada Bruno Silva!!!!! Funcionou!! Me desculpem sou iniciante em java!!!

Comment: Imagina Lizy, qualquer dúvida é só perguntar.

Comment: Só coloca que a minha resposta resolveu o seu problema, por favor :) rs